# AWS MSK Connect inserting data to s3 without additional folder of {topic_name}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-msk-connect

I am consuming a kafka topic (say, topic1) by using AWS MSK connect and sending to AWS s3.

The following is a simplified AWS MSK Connector config..

```
topics.dir=folder1/folder2
topics=topic1
```

The topic can be consumed and sent to s3 as expected.

The only problem is that an extra folder {topic_name} is created under s3 bucket, namely, folder1/folder2/topic1.

My question is:
Is there any way to disable the creation of new folder per topic_name?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Confluent S3 sink connector, you cannot avoid having a topic name as part of a object's path.

Here is a [code of a connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/TopicPartitionWriter.java#L582):

```
  private String fileKeyToCommit(String dirPrefix, long startOffset) {
    String name = tp.topic()
                      + fileDelim
                      + tp.partition()
                      + fileDelim
                      + String.format(zeroPadOffsetFormat, startOffset)
                      + extension;
    return fileKey(topicsDir, dirPrefix, name);
  }
```

As you can see, a connector unconditionally adds a topic name into a path of the object.

As a workaround, you can [enable events when new objects are created on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html), and rename the objects in Lambda.